Conical pulley system
I've been trying for days different ways to make the rope in this pulley work, but using a curve modifier to go around the cone doesn't make the right effect since the rope is supposed to be attached at the top of the cone while the cone rotates due to the force of pulling the rope through different pulleys.
Here's a video of what I got so far.
As you can see I somewhat managed to get the effect I need on the cone, but now I need the other half of the rope to follow it as it screws all the way up, but I don't know how to do  it.

In the image above you can see the first part of the rope, the one I need to pull to make the cone rotate, and it needs to be attached to the rope in the cone. I really don't know how to make the effect, maybe I can try something with bones but I still don't know how to approach it.

i'd suggest you use hook modifiers although it would be a bit tedious to set up. There's a YT video on building a drawbridge with a pulley system here which might help with the rigging section starting at around 4:50.
